# Маршрутизация между двумя итерфейсами

Tags: linux, маршрутизация

Есть сервер с двумя сетевыми картами.

- eth1 смотрит в сеть 192.168.1.0
- eth2 в 192.168.2.0

Есть два компьютера, comp1 подключен напрямую к серверу через eth1, comp2 подключен напрямую через eth2.
Прописал статические маршруты на сервере и на двух компах.

**Итог:** сервер пингует всех, а компы друг друга не могут.

comp1 пингует интерфейс eth2, а comp2 не видит.
comp2 пингует интерфейс eth1, а comp1 не видит.

Что я упустил?

Comment: У вас в `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` зачение `1` ? Если нет - запишите его туда, с помощью echo или /etc/sysctl.conf

Comment: @Mike Единичку поставил. Компы при пингу друг друга пишут Destination host undeachable.

Comment: Маска подсети на компах 255.255.255.0 ? И в качетсве шлюза по умолчанию стоит адрес вашего linux ? Еще могут быть запреты где нибудь в iptables в таблице FORWARD

Comment: @Mike Спасибо за ответы, не настроил на второй машине шлюз.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. на «среднем» компьютере должна быть разрешена передача пакетов между интерфейсами:

   ```
   $ echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
   ```

   для того, чтобы эта настройка применялась и после перезагрузки, раскомментируйте (или добавьте, если нет) строку в `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

   ```
   net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
   ```
2. убедитесь, что на прохождение пакетов не оказывают влияние правила *netfilter-а*. просмотреть их можно командой:

   ```
   $ sudo iptables-save
   ```
3. на «клиентских» компьютерах убедитесь, что сеть и маска сети установлены такие же, как и на соответствующих интерфейсах «среднего» компьютера.
4. на «клиентских» компьютерах должен быть либо добавлен маршрут по умолчанию через «средний» компьютер, либо добавлен конкретный маршрут ко второй сети, проходящий через «средний» компьютер.

Comment: Правила iptables смотрю обычно командой iptables -nvL  Но может использоваться и другой брандмауэр, а так же путаться под ногами selinux.

Comment: @dsnk, программы `iptables` и `iptables-save` обычно присутствуют во всех установках популярных дистрибутивов.

Comment: не так давно столкнулся с федорой, пришлось гасить firewalld, разбираться с его настройкой не было времени.

Comment: @dsnk, ну, это уже по поводу управления таблицами *netfilter*. а содержимое-то таблиц `iptables[-save]` покажет исправно.