# Подключение к IP-камере через OpenVPN

Tags: linux, iptables

Есть OpenVPN-сервер, через который некоторое количество компьютеров соединено в "локальную сеть" с адресами вида 10.10.1.Х

10.10.1.1 - это адрес сервера.

10.10.1.2 - это адрес машины, на которой я хочу видеть поток с IP-камеры.

10.10.1.3 - это Raspberry Pi 3, в eth0 которого подключена камера. Назначены статичные IP на камере(192.168.1.254) и на самой Pi(192.168.1.2). Основным шлюзом у них прописан 192.168.1.1.

Pi по wlan0 подключается к интернету, с помощью OpenVPN создается tun0(который получает адрес 10.10.1.3).

Со всех устройств ping прекрасно добивает до Pi и обратно(внутри OpenVPN сетки).
И застопорился я на "сцеплении" интерфейсов.

В результате хочу получить, чтобы по 10.10.1.3:554 я мог получить RTSP-поток.

Comment: а порт 554  прослушивается на всех сетевых интерфейсах? может в конфигурации он привязан к 192.168.1.2?

Comment: а вы уверены, что Pi у вас что-то вещает? ищите поток на 192.168.1.254 а чтоб до него добраться нужно прописать маршруты из 10.10.x.x в 192.168.1.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> хочу получить, чтобы по 10.10.1.3:554 я мог получить RTSP-поток

на машине с ip-адресом 10.10.1.3 надо добавить два правила *netfilter-а* — для *dnat* и для *snat*. приблизительно так:

```
$ iptables -A PREROUTING -i tun0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 554 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.254
$ iptables -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.2
```

смысл *dnat*-правила в том, чтобы у пакетов, пришедших на интерфейс tun0, порт 554, подменялся адрес назначения — на 192.168.1.254.

эти пакеты будут уходить через интерфейс eth0, где и сработает уже *snat*-правило, подменяющее адрес источника — на 192.168.1.2. смысл этого правила в том, чтобы когда ip-камера будет посылать ответные пакеты, оно слало их на этот адрес. netfilter при этом подменит адреса назначения и источника на «исходные», чтобы ответный пакет ушёл в правильном направлении и с правильным обратным адресом.

---

ах, да, стоит упомянуть, что на этой же машине должна быть разрешена передача пакетов между интерфейсами. смотрите, например, [первый пункт этого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/525245/178576).

Comment: Спасибо. Это сработало. И это намного проще, чем всё найденное в интернетах до этого.